# Merge clamAV with YARA and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, yara

I want to merge clamAV python and YARA rules. The target is to, on demand, scan with YARA rules that i have made. 
I wrote this simple script and work just fine

```
import pyclamd
cd=pyclamd.ClamdAgnostic()
x=cd.scan_file('/home/john/Desktop/workSpace/yara/2.pdf')
if x is False: 
    print ("no ")
else :
    print ("Yes")
```

is there a way to scan the same .pdf file using YARA rules BUT through pyclamd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer. It seems that ClamAV can read *.yara files and search additionally to the existed virus database. The solution is to put a yara rule to the /var/lib/clamav directory. The code need a little modification just to reload the  ClamdAgnostic() and voila.

```
import pyclamd
cd=pyclamd.ClamdAgnostic()
cd.reload()
x=cd.scan_file('/home/john/Desktop/workSpace/yara/2.pdf)
print (x)
```

If the rule is true then you will see a print output with the rule that is used

```
{'/home/john/Desktop/workSpace/yara/2.pdf': ('FOUND', 'YARA.testFor2.UNOFFICIAL')}
```

else the output will be Null